# How to create tag with namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to add a prefix to a tag to represent a particular namespace - as can be seen below

```
String envelopePrefix = "omgEnv";
            String businessPrefix = "omgBS";
            String namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/";

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("OmgeoMessageContainer");

            rootElement.setAttributeNS(namespaceURI, "xmlns:" + envelopePrefix, "http://www.omgeo.com/schema/v1.0/envelope");
            rootElement.setAttributeNS(namespaceURI, "xmlns:" + businessPrefix, "http://www.omgeo.com/schema/v1.0/BusinessServices");

            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Element messageParties = doc.createElementNS(namespaceURI, envelopePrefix + ":MessageParties");
            rootElement.appendChild(messageParties);
```

Unfortunately my messageParties element is failing with the following error -

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create
>   or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to
>   namespaces.

How are you supposed to prefix a tag with the correct namespace definition? Event the setPrefix method throws the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can decide the prefix for a namespace element while generating XML. I did not see any such option in the JavaDocs. To create element with namespace this should be the modification.

```
String namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/";
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElementNS(namespaceURI, "OmgeoMessageContainer");

doc.appendChild(rootElement);
Element messageParties = doc.createElementNS(namespaceURI, "MessageParties");
rootElement.appendChild(messageParties);
```

This will generate the XML with auto decided prefix for the namespaces.